# Where should i dispatch an async action to save an input onBlur?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have three components. First there is an EditableField component, which I want to toggle between showing an h3 tag and an input that a user can type more text into (this part works). OnBlur, the input should then change back to an h3 with the updated text (also works) and dispatch a backend request to persist the new value of the h3 (this part does not work). The EditableField is rendered into a Card component and the Card Component is rendered in a CardList component which contains the backend data for the array of cards.

I am having difficulty figuring out 1) which component should control dispatching the backend request to persist the new text value? and 2) Depending on the answer to #1, how can I access the updated value of the input text? As an aside, I've verified in postman that my current route works. I'll post it below after my components.

```
class EditableField extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: this.props.text
        }
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
    }
    render() {
        const { text } = this.state;
        if(this.props.isEditing) {
            return (
                <input value={ text } type='text'
                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                    onBlur={this.props.handleToggle} autoFocus />
            )
        }
        return (
            <h3 onClick={ this.props.handleToggle }
                {text}
            </h3>
        )
    }
}
export default EditableField;

class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isEditing: false
        };
    }
    handleToggle = () => {
        this.setState({ isEditing: !this.state.isEditing });
        this.handleBlur(this.props._id, this.props.title);
        // the above handleBlur does not work
    }
    handleBlur = async (id, text) => {
        const res = await axios.put(`/api/surveys/${id}`, text);
    }
    render() {
        const { isEditing } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6  my-3">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <div className="card-title">
                            <EditableField 
                                text={this.props.title} 
                                isEditing={isEditing}
                                handleToggle={this.handleToggle} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
export default Card;
export class CardList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false
        }
    }    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCards();
    }    
    renderSurveys() {
        return this.props.cards.reverse().map(({ _id, title, body, dateSent, yes, no}) => {
            return (
                <Card key={_id} title={title}
                    body={body} dateSent={dateSent}
                    yes={yes} no={no} _id={_id}
                    onDelete={ () => {
                        this.props.deleteSurvey(_id) 
                        }} />
            )
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { isLoading } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                { isLoading && <LoadingIndicator /> }
                <div className="row">
                    {this.renderSurveys()}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
} 
function mapStateToProps({ cards: { cards, isLoading }}) {
    return {
        cards,
        isLoading
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCards, deleteCard })(CardList);

app.put('/api/surveys/:surveyId', async (req, res) => {
        const { title } = req.body;
        try {
             await Survey.updateOne({ _id: req.params.surveyId }, {
                $set: { title }
            })
            .exec();
            res.send('ok').status(200);
        }
        catch(e) {
            res.send(e).status(400);
        }
    });
```